# Regarding Binning of the values in python

Tags: python, integer, decimal, bins

I have a set of values as :-

```
1.2 
1.0 
2.6 
2.4 
2.8 
5.1 
2.5 
5.4 
1.3 
1.1 
10.3 
4.1 
3.4 
3.2 
6.1 
6.3 
9.0 
8.6 
7.1 
3.2 
4.3 
15.0 
12.3 
13.1 
17.4 
10.2 
11.7 
14.6 
16.3
```

Now, how can i bin them into groups such that the decimal values will go to the nearest integer value and give the no of its occurrence. ie.,say if value is 1.2 it should go to 1.0 and if value is 8.6 it should go to 9 (its nearest integer).

and i want the output as:-

```
0.0 - 1.0    its occurrence
1.1 - 2.0    its occurrence
2.1 - 3.0    its occurrence
3.1 - 4.0    its occurrence
4.1 - 5.0    its occurrence
16.1 - 17.0  its occurrence
```

and hence i can get the bins as x axis and its no.of times of occurrence on y axis and hence plot the graph.
How can i write a python program for this..??

Comment: Look up "histogram" on Google.

Comment: I want to write a python program for this... kindly help me out

Comment: I am sure that you do. However, SO is not a free coding site. I refuse to help you if you do not want to put a minimal effort into this yourself, unless you pay me for my time.

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(round(f) for f in values)
```

alternatively (if numpy is available),

```
import numpy as np

minval = int(min(values))
maxval = int(max(values)) + 1.
bins = np.arange(minval, maxval + 1, 1.)
hist, edges = np.histogram(values, bins)
```

then for display,

```
for lo, hi, num in zip(edges, edges[1:], hist):
    print("{} - {}: {}".format(lo, hi, num))
```

gives

```
1.0 - 2.0: 4
2.0 - 3.0: 4
3.0 - 4.0: 3
4.0 - 5.0: 2
5.0 - 6.0: 2
6.0 - 7.0: 2
7.0 - 8.0: 1
8.0 - 9.0: 1
9.0 - 10.0: 1
10.0 - 11.0: 2
11.0 - 12.0: 1
12.0 - 13.0: 1
13.0 - 14.0: 1
14.0 - 15.0: 1
15.0 - 16.0: 1
16.0 - 17.0: 1
17.0 - 18.0: 1
```

Comment: But how can i get it in this form                                                                         1.0   4                                                                                                                  2.0   1                                                                                                                      3.0   6                                                                                                                           4.0   2    and so on...... ie., removing the semicolon and commas.....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that input numbers are a list we can do the following:

from collections import Counter

count_numbers=dict(Counter([round(x) for x in list_numbers]))

your result would be

{1.0: 4, 2.0: 1, 3.0: 6, 4.0: 2, 5.0: 2, 6.0: 2, 7.0: 1, 9.0: 2, 10.0: 2, 12.0: 2, 13.0: 1, 15.0: 2, 16.0: 1, 17.0: 1}

Comment: My inputs are in the file, and can u kindly elaborate the code, what else should i add in the code....

Comment: parse the file into a object and the above code should work.

Comment: But how can i get it in this form                                                                         1.0     4                                                                                                                         2.0     1                                                                                                                     3.0     6                                                                                                                     4.0     2   and so on...... ie., removing the semicolon and commas.....